# Emission of photoelectrons by irradiating it with a sufficiently energetic photon beam

Tags: energy, photons, photoelectric-effect, metals

Let's say we irradiate a metal with a photon beam whose energy per quanta is 10 times the work function of the metal, say 10(k). So post absorption it will have the same energy, and say it collides with another metal atom in its lattice such that it transfers 4k energy to the other atom and still posses 6k, again we assume that they must've collided with other atoms and by the time they reach the metal surface they have energy 4k and 3k respectively( solely made up just to imply that their energies are more than the work function). Now both possess the energy to break free and will do so. Therefore one photon ended up energizing and emitting two electrons indirectly.

Kindly correct me wherever I am wrong.

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html

Comment: remember the energy of the photon is connected to hnu , i.e. the frequency in the plot I linked. You will just be getting a point high on the right

Answer (score 2):

Photoelectric effect is one-one process that is the incoming photon will transfer its whole energy to one electron which will result in ejection of electron and rest of the energy will be converted into kinetic energy of electron.